# Jquery date picker set date issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery UI date-picker. Currently its working well. but when user change his computer date, my date picker set date is changed. how i stop that. please check below image.

[image: issue]

today is 2019-10-24. but when i change it to 2019-10-20, it affects to the date picker set date. How i prevent this.

if u know, please provide simple sample.

Comment: you can use setDate attribute to set your custom date like: ```$('#txtDate').datepicker('setDate', '12/31/2000');```

Comment: i do not want to use custom date. i ask , how to prevent this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Remember that JavaScript gets the Date from the Operating System. This is the basis for the date unless you set the date specifically using `setDate` method.